# ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0

Tags: android, react-native

I have no idea why android keep doing this to me. When I change gradle classpath to 3.3.2,I have this problem:
[image: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1']

If I change it to 3.2.1 I get this error:
[image: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1']

I allmost tried everything could any one help me?

this is my project build.gradle

```
buildscript {
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.2"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
}
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
}
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
//      mavenLocal()
//      mavenCentral()

        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.10.1'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

and this is my app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
import com.android.build.OutputFile

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.newproject2"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  
}

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

I I have tried react-native version 0.59,0.58 and 0.57 and I'm kind of sure that this is a problem with gradle

Comment: did u try `ext.version = [ supportLibVersion: "28.0.0"]` inside your apps build.gradle and loading like `"com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${version.supportLibVersion}"` already?

Comment: in project build.gradle buildscript i have ext that i imported in my app build.gradle which use supportLibVersion: "28.0.0", however i used 28.0.0 like `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0` directly but it  didn't work

Comment: @molood was it working before you change your gradle classPath ?

Comment: no it didn't worked at all

Comment: @molood Try to open you Sdk manager -> SDK tools -> make sure Android Support Repository 47.0.0 is installed

Comment: @Hend yes it installed

Comment: @molood could you take a screen shot of the content of this path Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli this the link of my appcompat-v7 [https://imgur.com/a/GgCs0Iy]

Comment: @molood try this     `implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+`

Comment: if i delete `maven {url "$rootDir/../node_modules/reactnative/android"}` and use `implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+"` it'll sync successfully but if i don't delete maven i have the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191127/discussion-between-hend-el-sahli-and-molood-ayat).

Comment: @moloodayat I guess this `maven` line should not be touched ... but try in your terminal `>cd android` then `gradlew clean` ... and if this project is not an empty project ... try to create a brand new project and use it now for testing

Comment: lets continue this discussion in chat

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your buidl.gradle (project)

```
allprojects {
repositories {
...
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
...
}
```

}

In the [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup)
 it states that if you are using a version of gradle lower than 4.1, you must add this to your build.gradle file

Comment: unfortunatly didn't worked, I even change the position of jcenter() and `maven {url 'https://maven.google.com/' name 'Google'
        }` or I added it also in my buildscript's repositories but it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

Try to invalidate cache on "File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart"